# Why does create Browser Link 4-6 Mpbs local network load?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, signalr, browser-link

This is a follow up question to [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27038851/why-does-an-idle-signalr-connection-have-4-6-mbps-network-load-locally) where I thought my SignalR connection creates the network load.

But as it showed it's the Browser Link from Visual Studio that generates the load. So disabling it helps, and as I'm not really depending on it it's an OK solution for me. But I'd like to understand why this happens and maybe prevent it for the future.

The solution itself is a fairly complex RequireJS/Backbone/Marionette/et al... app. So might it be related to the general (complex) solution structure? Are there known issues with libraries in general?

I think the issue started after installing 2013 Update 4 RC. At least I didn't notice that issue before.

Comment: The only solution I found was to disable Browser Link. Still don't know why the load is generated. But not really missing Browser Link for now. See the linked question.